# Articles about image processing/manipulation

Tags: image, graphics, image-processing

Do you have any links/books with information about digital image processing (filters/effects)? I'd like a large list of filters and information on how they work and how to implement them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [large list](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/genindex.html)

Among them my favorites are Invert, GaussianBlur, Canny, HoughLinesP, Lanczos, cvBlobsLib

Comment: Thank you. That was a rather large one, great! :)